# Why won't this string escape?

Tags: javascript, python, html, escaping, web2py

usI have some html with an onSubmit:

```
<form id="login_box" onSubmit="alert('{{=T('Thank you for contacting us! We have received your email and will contact you shortly.')}}'); this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">
```

The problem is that no matter what I do it won't escape the nested quotes. I've tried:

```
<form id="login_box" onSubmit="alert('{{=T(\'Thank you for contacting us! We have received your email and will contact you shortly.\')}}'); this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">

<form id="login_box" onSubmit="alert(\"{{=T('Thank you for contacting us! We have received your email and will contact you shortly.')}}\"); this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">

<form id="login_box" onSubmit=\"alert(\\"{{=T('Thank you for contacting us! We have received your email and will contact you shortly.')}}\\"); this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;\">
```

And any other combo I can think of even if I know it won't work. Nothing I try is escaping the nested quotes.

Comment: This is the generated HTML? What is `{{=`? (I guess `T(...)` is some kind of translation function).

Comment: can you tell me what does this have to do with python?

Comment: Alternate the string symbol. 'he said "hello, she said 'goodbye'"'

Comment: @Felix {{=T(' is the python translate function. It's translating the message inside the alert.

Comment: @James, the first one does seem to be escaped properly but it returns with invalid python function.

Comment: How does the {{=T()}} thing work?

Comment: It's programmed to find everything encapsulated by {{=T('')}} and translate it. I think in php it's just <?php render t(something) ?> I think...

Comment: What framework are you using in Python?

Comment: So this is *not* the generated HTML. Have a look at that an escape the quotes accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using twig or any similar template system in python.

If you want to translate `{{=T('message to translate')}}`, just put that string into a custom attr.

### Example:

```
<form id="login_box" msg="{{=T('Thank you for contacting us! We have received your email and will contact you shortly.')}}" onSubmit="alert(this.getAttribute('msg')); this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">
```

[the example](http://jsfiddle.net/JPm93/2/)

:)

Comment: I'm using web2py. This looks like it might work but can't test it until morning. Will let you know.

Comment: It seems it wants to work. But it only returns 'undefined.' http://jsfiddle.net/JPm93/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JPm93/2/ It seems the attr must be accessed by get Attribute(). I updated the example

Comment: Works just fine now. Thanks. I need to refresh all my getDocument/getAttribute/etc knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is in a web2py template, your original code:

```
onSubmit="alert('{{=T('Thank you for contacting us! We have received your email and will contact you shortly.')}}'); this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;"
```

generates the following HTML:

```
onSubmit="alert('Thank you for contacting us! We have received your email and will contact you shortly.'); this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;"
```

which as far as I can tell, works fine in the browser. However, if you want to escape those single quotes inside the alert, you can do:

```
onSubmit="alert({{="'%s'" % T('Thank you for contacting us! We have received your email and will contact you shortly.')}}); this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;"
```

which will generate the following HTML:

```
onSubmit="alert(&#x27;Thank you for contacting us! We have received your email and will contact you shortly.&#x27;); this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;"
```

which should also work in the browser.

Everything inside the `{{ }}` delimiters is Python code and will be executed on the server and escaped before writing into the response. Everything outside the `{{ }}` delimiters will be included in the response as is (i.e., no escaping done by web2py). In your original code, the single quotes in the alert are outside the web2py template delimiters, so they are not escaped by web2py and simply delivered as is. This is explained further in [this section](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/5#The-views) of the web2py book.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML attributes, some characters (`"` and `&`) have to be encoded as HTML entities. In javascript strings, the string delimiter (eg `'`), has to be escaped using a backslash. This means that your first one should work.

```
<form id="login_box" onSubmit="alert('{{=T(\'Thank you for contacting us! We have received your email and will contact you shortly.\')}}'); this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">
```

This should alert `{{=T('Thank you for contacting us! We have received your email and will contact you shortly.')}}` when you click it. Assuming this is what you want?

**Edit:**

```
{{=T('Thank you for contacting us! We have received your email and will contact you shortly.')}}
```

will return a string, so

```
<form id="login_box" onSubmit="alert('{{=T('Thank you for contacting us! We have received your email and will contact you shortly.')}}'); this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">
```

will become

```
<form id="login_box" onSubmit="alert('Thank you for contacting us! We have received your email and will contact you shortly.'); this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">
```

in rendered HTML. This is correct. However, you need to escape any backslashes, then html entity encode the output of the T function (in that order).

Comment: I think this is not what OP wants, as `T` is a Python function (as mentioned in the comments) that should be called, maybe part of the template OP is using?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't read/see that. Is `{{= }}` some sort of template syntax?

Comment: Yes it is the proper syntax `{{= }}` and works well within other js scripts, however, this particular one doesn't want to work right since it's inside the alert. If I try and escape the inner ' the python will reject it. If I try to change the alert's quote to " and try to escape that based on the containing " then the js rejects it. As in `onSubmit="alert(\"{{=T('`. Although I don't know why this is the case...

Answer (score 0):

HTML-encode the the returned value, and then encode that as JSON.

Comment: The other way round. JSON encode first, then HTML entity encode. Its javascript in HTML, not HTML in javascript.